# Logging/Monitoring of Kubernetes cluster in Azure Contianer Service

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-monitoring

Does Azure Container Service integrate with Azure Monitor?
Wondering what the best way is to do logging/monitoring of kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Do you mind using third party products and services outside azure's stack?

Comment: Open to using 3rd party - any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at Datadog, it is easy enough to setup and use and I am in no way affiliated to Datadog. The setup takes a few minutes and allows you to truly customise your dashboard and alerts. From my own experience it was simple and cost effective

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for monitoring tools on Azure, you may want to use Azure OMS (Opertation Management Suite). This gives you the ability to monitor the container inventory, performance, and logs in a single location. To my understanding, the stats of the container is only available for Linux nodes now, if you are deploying your k8s cluster on the Azure Portal.

To do this, you need to first create an OMS account. By this time, you should have the Workspace ID and the key available. The next step would 
be to create the oms pod on each node using a DaemonSet.

For the detailed setup, take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-oms.

For third party tools, Grafana+influxdb is one of the ways I have tried before. Basically it provides you with the metrics on two levels: POD and NODE respectively. The displayed metrics included CPU Usage, Memory Usage, Network Usage and Filesystem Usage, etc. Of course, you can always alter your query to add extra metrics.

For the implementation of this approach, you can refer to https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/kubernetes/monitoring.md.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi isw, welcome to SO! It may be worthwhile explaining the information found on the other side of the links in case they go dead in the future.

Comment: The script for the daemon set is available here https://github.com/Microsoft/OMS-docker/tree/master/Kubernetes.

Comment: Hi isw - thanks for the info. So, my question actually stemmed from the tutorial you pointed to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-oms.
With OMS it seems I can just monitor the cluster itself (e.g. container events, errors, CPU, memory usage, etc.). I cannot see the logs and metrics that are being generated by my application itself. So, in that sense it seems OMS is lacking. Hence was wondering does Azure Monitor fill that gap?

Comment: Hi Rajeev, may I know if you are deploying your k8s cluster using the portal or acs-engine? Also, are you using Windows nodes or Linux one? Or could you provide more info. for the application you are trying to monitor. To my understanding, Azure Monitor just provides you with a single point (dashboard) to monitor all your Azure Resources. It can integrate with various tools like Application Insights, OMS to provide you with extra monitoring capabilities.

Comment: In this sense, if you want to monitor container (pods) performance in the k8s cluster on Azure, you should go for Log Analytics (OMS) as described here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/log-analytics/log-analytics-containers.md. And if it happens you are using Windows nodes, I suggest you can try the followings https://github.com/Microsoft/OMS-docker/tree/master/Kubernetes/windows. It is updated a few dates ago and Windows Container Monitoring in k8s should now be possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this CLI command to browse through kubernetes cluster deployed using azure container service.

az acs kubernetes browse -g -n

This way you can see kubernetes webui
also you can use kubectl proxy command.